# Select one element at a time using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I have multiple input checkboxes wrapped up in p tags `<p><input type="checkbox" /></p>`. I'm trying to change the `background-color` of the P tag when the checkbox is `:checked` The problem I'm having is that all of the `<p> </p>` tags background colors are changing at the same time. I only want the current paragraph tag `background-color` to change.

**HTML**

```or-tag-here
<p>
  <input type="checkbox"  />
  <label>Animals &amp; Pets</label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox"  />
  <label>Business &amp; Finance</label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>Auto's &amp; Cycles</label>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```or-tag-here
.highlight { background-color: #DDD; }
```

**jQuery**

```or-tag-here
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('p').addClass('highlight')
    } else {
  $('p').removeClass('highlight')
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('input').change(function () {
    if ( this.checked ) {
        $(this).closest('p').addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('p').removeClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

---

You can also make this a little shorter by using [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$('input').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('p').toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Also recommend caching `$(this)` for a small but clean performance tip.

Comment: @Brombomb - It's only being used once, so no caching needed.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I like the conciseness and clarity of this code the best. One thing I failed to mention was what if I set the input to checked="checked". How do I keep the highlight.

Comment: @Eric - Not sure I'm following you. Are you asking how to make sure that the highlight state is correctly reflected on page load? If so, then just trigger the `change` event on those `input`s on page load: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KSgR6/).

Comment: Yes it's actually going to be implemented in a ruby on rails app. On the server side I'm going to have some check boxes already checked. So for example if I add checked="checked" to the input how can I make sure that the tag is highlighted when the page loads.

Comment: I see what you did there. Excellent! Made my day. Now I can sleep tight. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

You can target the parent paragraph with `closest()`, and use `toggleClass()` to toggle the class, and the `change` event would be the proper event to listen for when changing a checkbox :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest('p').toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NsyVe/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo. I appreciate the example on Fiddle. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` isntead of just `p`. Then get its parent using `.parent()`

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input').click(function() {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             $(this).parent().addClass('highlight')
           } else {
              $(this).parent().removeClass('highlight')
          }
     });
   });
```